# Client initiating data connection in ftp active mode?

Tags: networking, tcp, ftp

I am trying to understand how FTP protocol works.

Basically, the text says that -in active mode- client first initiates connection on connection port, and following that server will initiate connection on the data port. However, the data connection might fail if client is running behind a NAT.

My question is why can't client initiate connection on data port just like connection port. Why do have the need for the server to initiate connection on data port?

Answer (score 2):

> why can't client initiate connection on data port just like connection port

When the client initiates the data connection, it's called the "passive" mode.

It's called "passive" because the server waits for a connection instead of "actively" opening one.

Comment: My question is why does the protocol require the serve to initiate the data connection? What we do gain by server initiating the connection. Because in client server model, it is usually the client that initiates the connection.

Comment: One of them has to initiate the connection. It can be the server, or the client. If it's the server, we call it "active mode", if it's the client we call it "passive mode." As to why does active mode even exist, the original design of FTP predates NATs and firewalls, so there was no issue with the server making connections to the client.